# Is there a way to add calevents to DateEntry in tkcalendar?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am trying to find a way to highlight specific dates on tkcalendar's DateEntry class.

This is running on Python 3. It works successfully with tkcalendar's Calendar class, but does not seem to apply to DateEntry class.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

window = tk.Tk()
cal = DateEntry(window)
date = cal.datetime.today() + cal.timedelta(days=2)
cal.calevent_create(date, 'Hello World', 'message')
cal.tag_config('message', background='red', foreground='yellow')
cal.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

This works if we define cal=Calendar(window), but fails whenever I try to switch it over to DateEntry.

> **Copy Comment**: Changing cal to a Calendar object and then adding:
>
> ```
> de=DateEntry(window)  
> de.pack()  
> de.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", cal.calevent_create(date, 'Hello World', 'message'))
> ```
>
> doesn't seem to be working for me... I just end up getting a
>
> ```
> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
> ```
>
> whenever I try to select a date.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I am just trying to merge the DateEntry functionality with the ability to create calevents. Does this only work for Calendar? It seems odd to me that DateEntry would not also be able to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I get what you mean. I've added a method `def callback(event): cal.calevent_create(date, 'Hello World', 'message')`, and changed the binding to just `callback`. I'm no longer receiving an error, but the desired date is not highlighted on the DateEntry box.

Comment: If you really want to add events in the calendar drop-down of the DateEntry, then you can access it via the `_calendar` attribute of the DateEntry. But maybe what you want to do is for the user to select a date to add an event on a different calendar?

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: Is there a way to add calevents to DateEntry in tkcalendar?

No, `DateEntry` is for **selecting** one Date.
`Calendar` is for holding Calendar Events based on Date.

---

You have to `bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", ...` and in the `def callback(...` do `<ref to Calendar>.calevent_create(<selected date>, 'Hello ...'`

- [Calendar](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Calendar.html#calendar)
- [DateEntry](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/DateEntry.html#dateentry)
- [DateEntry - virtual-events](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/DateEntry.html#virtual-events)
- [Tkinter Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

window = tk.Tk()

def date_entry_selected(event):
    w = event.widget
    date = w.get_date()
    print('Selected Date:{}'.format(date))
    # <ref to Calendar>.calevent_create(date, 'Hello ...`)
    cal.calevent_create(date, 'Hello ...')

cal = Calendar(window, selectmode='day', year=2019, month=10, day=28)
cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

de=DateEntry(window)  
de.pack()  
de.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", date_entry_selected)  

window.mainloop()
```